# Resource not found after upgrade to Api-platform 2.7

Tags: php, api, symfony, api-platform.com

I want to upgrade my api which currently uses **PHP8.1**, **Symfony 6.1** and **Api-Platform 2.6** to **Api-Platform 3.0**.
So I first upgraded to Api-Platform 2.7 and switched the **metadata_backward_compatibility_layer** flag to false.

All "**getCollection**" are in error now while all other endpoints are working normally.

The exception thrown is **ApiPlatform\Exception\ResourceClassNotFoundException** with the following message: Resource "**App\Entity\RatingAttribute**" not found.

Here is the entity in question:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Patch;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table("rating_attribute")]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [new Get(), new Patch(), new GetCollection(), new Post()],
    paginationEnabled: false
)]
class RatingAttribute extends AbstractReadWriteProperties
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer', nullable: true)]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Rating::class)]
    private Rating $rating;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 240)]
    private string $key;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 240)]
    private string $value;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'bigint', length: 240)]
    private string $reviewToken;

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Rating
     */
    public function getRating(): Rating
    {
        return $this->rating;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKey(): string
    {
        return $this->key;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue(): string
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReviewToken(): string
    {
        return $this->reviewToken;
    }

    /**
     * @param Rating $rating
     *
     * @return RatingAttribute
     */
    public function setRating(Rating $rating): RatingAttribute
    {
        $this->rating = $rating;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $key
     *
     * @return RatingAttribute
     */
    public function setKey(string $key): RatingAttribute
    {
        $this->key = $key;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     *
     * @return RatingAttribute
     */
    public function setValue(string $value): RatingAttribute
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $reviewToken
     *
     * @return RatingAttribute
     */
    public function setReviewToken(string $reviewToken): RatingAttribute
    {
        $this->reviewToken = $reviewToken;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I don't understand what can happen, the problem seems to come from the **vendor/api-platform/core/src/Core/Metadata/Resource/Factory/ExtractorResourceMetadataFactory.php** line **54**

If I comment this part in this code :

```
if (!(class_exists($resourceClass) || interface_exists($resourceClass)) || !$resource = $this->extractor->getResources()[$resourceClass] ?? false) {
    return $this->handleNotFound($parentResourceMetadata, $resourceClass);
}
```

everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tried the upgrade to **Api-Platform 3.0** and it worked (after several code changes).

I think the **metadata_backward_compatibility_layer** flag set to false in 2.6 does not allow to have a functional api but **ONLY** to test the validity of the entities.

So the problem is solved for me, but it was not clear in the documentation.